# 2 UIButtons to set 2 UIImageViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I've 2 `UIButton`s, I want both buttons to pick an image, `button1` is setting an image to `imageview1` and `button2` to `imageView2`. I now created `button1` which picks an image and set `imageView1` to that image, but if I'm creating `button2`, I don't now what I have to do in:

```
- (IBAction)chooseImage1:(id)sender {
     imagePicker.delegate = self;
     imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
     [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)chooseImage2:(id)sender {
     imagePicker.delegate = self;
     imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
     [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

UIImage *image;

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

      NSURL *mediaURL;
      mediaURL = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
      image = (UIImage *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

     imageView1.image=image;
     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Nah, not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index in your `.h` file. Something like

```
NSUInteger *selectedImageIndex;
```

And in your `.m` file :

```
- (void)showImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)source{
    UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.sourceType = source;
    ipc.allowsEditing = YES;
    ipc.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)chooseImage1:(id)sender {
    selectedImageIndex = 1;
    [self showImagePicker:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}

- (IBAction)chooseImage2:(id)sender {
    selectedImageIndex = 2;
    [self showImagePicker:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}    

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
        if (!img)
           img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

        if (selectedImageIndex == 1)
           imageView1.image=img;
        else
           imageView2.image = img;

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
       [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But then again, this is just one way to do it.

Comment: You probably want to set the index to 2 in chooseImage2: instead of 1.